# Create default project model object after user sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my app when a user is created or signed in newly there should be default project called "Users" in his account. How to make it?

I am using devise for signin and signup of a user.  After the user is signed in he can create a project and work on it. But now I want a default project present already when a user signs up.

Comment: I am using devise for signin and signup of a user. and after the user is signed in he can create a project and work on it. But now I want a default project present already when a user signs up.

Comment: @rails.newbie Make a method,named lets say new_proj, where you can create a project for signed in users and after that you need to override devise registrations_controller's create method. Call your new_proj method from registrations_controllers create method.

Comment: Can I user after_create call back in the model to call the method? If so how to call with user_id? @user2675613

Comment: @rails.newbie you can but i think a better approach would be what i described above

Comment: I could get this with call backs even more easily... that was easier in my app. thanks for your reply @user2675613

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So called [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) will serve you well:

In your model, you add something similar to:

**user.rb**

```
# this calls the function defined below after the creation of a user
after_create :default_project

# put callback functions into the private sector, as it will only be used for this model
private

  def default_project
    Project.create(:user_id => this.id, :name => "Users", ...)
    # do more stuff
  end
```